# Adding Seats to the gojs nodes

Tags: gojs

Here the link contains different tables and seats around it http://gojs.net/latest/samples/seatingChart.html  I put two buttons one for adding seat and another for removing seat now i want add the seat when clicking addseat button and remove seat when clicking remove button Please Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I Implement code like this 
if we want to add a seat to the table use fallowing

```
myDiagram.findNodeForKey(keyId).add(Seat(1,"0.2 0","0.5 0"));
```

we will get keyId like this

```
 keyId= obj.part.data.key
```

If we want to remove the seat to table use fallowing

```
myDiagram.findNodeForKey(keyId).removeAt(seatno);
```

That's it!